# Having function as argument in setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm simply trying to pass a function to a setInterval function. Doesn't seem to be working with my code. Right now the code below works at first, but how would I pass my function parameters when calling the setInterval function?

```
//Works here

ajaxUpdateOne(function(countOne,countTwo) {
    var itemCount = countOne;
    var totalCount = countTwo;
    console.log(itemCount);
    console.log(totalCount);
});

//Does not work here.

var myVar = ajaxUpdateOne(function(countOne,countTwo) {
    var itemCount = countOne;
    var totalCount = countTwo;
    console.log(itemCount);
    console.log(totalCount);
});

setInterval(myVar,8000);
```

Comment: your setInterval is being passed undefined, not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the code you posted is partial, and it is not clear what `ajaxUpdateOne()` does, I am assuming it calls `$.ajax()` and updates the page based on the response results. However, to be able to pass parameters into the function called later in `setInterval()`, following construct can be used:

```
var deferredUpdate = function(countOne, countTwo) {
  return function() { ajaxUpdateOne(countOne, countTwo); }
}


setInterval(deferredUpdate(42,3), 8000);
setInterval(deferredUpdate(1,2), 2000);
```

The trick here is that your `deferredUpdate()` returns a function itself, not a value. However the parameters for this resulting function are bound in the particular closure. This is one of the basic techniques in functional programming.

Comment: This is a really good explanation. I've had a lot of trouble understanding these techniques. Thanks Alex.

Comment: Thanks! Please, mark it as an answer if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: So basically what you call in the arguments gets passed to the return.

Comment: Correct. Another way of thinking about it is `return eval("function() { foo("+countOne+","+countTwo+"); }");` - here you lock your argument into a string of code and then turn this code into a function variable with constants. In practice, closure is much more efficient, but the effect is very similar.

Answer (score 3):

Currently you are calling `ajaxUpdateOne()` with anonymous function as an argument. `myVar` is not a function.

Change Your code as

```
var myVar = function () {
    ajaxUpdateOne(function (countOne, countTwo) {
        var itemCount = countOne;
        var totalCount = countTwo;
        console.log(itemCount);
        console.log(totalCount);
    });
}
setInterval(myVar, 8000);
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that I did not have a function for myVar. So in order for it to pass in the setInterval method I have to make it a function it looks like, right?